# How can I assign a list to a torch.tensor?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

Assume that I have a list `[(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)]` and another list `[4,5,6]` and a matrix X with size is (3,2). I am trying to assign the list to the matrix like `X[0,0] = 4`, `X[1,0] = 5` and `X[1,1] = 6`. But it seems like I have a problem of assigning a list to tensor

```
x = torch.zeros(3,2)
indices = [(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)]
value = [4,5,6]
x[indices] = values
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-dec4e6a479a5> in <module>
     
   4 indices = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
 
   5 values = [4, 5, 6]

----> 6 x[indices] = values

TypeError: can't assign a list to a torch.FloatTensor
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can make `indices` tensor than it would make indexing easy

```py
indices = torch.tensor([(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)])

x[indices[:,0], indices[:,1]] = torch.tensor(values).float()
x
tensor([[4., 0.],
        [5., 6.],
        [0., 0.]])
```

As our `x` is float type we need to convert values to same.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer to "how do I change a list to a Tensor" is to use `torch.Tensor(list)`. But that will not solve your actual problem here.

One way would be to associate the index and value and then iterate over them:

```
for (i,v) in zip(indices,values) :
   x[i] = v
```

Comment: No problem! If you could accept the answer, I'd appreciate it.